What are these pillars attached to foundation wall
Not sure what these pillars are, they are cemented to the wall. My wall is bowing in so not sure if the was a attempt to stop it back in the day.

Are they cemented to the wall, or are they cast into the wall?

I believe they are called pilasters, at least on the east coast. I am used to seeing them on the inside of a basement to reinforce a wall for load bearing where beams are placed. This looks like an application to reinforce the wall since it is on the outside.
If there is a full basement and the walls are only 8 inches thick, that is the reason they are there. Back in the 80s or so, before the code went the ICC building code, the had to be 12 inches thick of CMU (Concrete Masonry Unit, cinder block, slag block hollow core block) if there was more than 5 feet of fill against the outside. If you do have a full basement with only 8" thick walls, and it appears you have certainly more than 5' of fill against the wall, I can see how it would keep the walls from buckling horizontally, but it still will let the wall move in gradually in at the top, creating a long inward bow in the wall. The pressure of the weight of the house and the anchor bolts that are typically spaced 4' apart are the only things to keep it from bowing
